# Select Database names and extended properties in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, extended-properties

I have three databases, starting with "MD_" that I have added in SQL Server 2012.
Each of them has an extended property NAME = "DESCRIPTION"

What I like to have returned is a result set of the database names and the "DESCRIPTION" value.

Selecting the database names are easy enough but I could use some help with joining in the extended property.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT A.NAME
    FROM sys.databases A
    Where LEFT(A.NAME, 3) = 'MD_'
END
```

Results:

```
NAME   DESCRIPTION
MD_1   Initial
MD_2   Secondary
MD_3   Final
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Kind regards

Comment: consider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186989(v=sql.90).aspx or similar stack question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714848/select-extended-property-from-sql-server-tables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link in the comments helped me get here but sys.extended_properties is a per database view.  So the properties for each database are contained in the database.  This worked though.

```
CREATE TABLE #EP (DatabaseName varchar(255), PropertyName varchar(max), 
            PropertyValue varchar(max))

EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'INSERT INTO #EP SELECT ''?'' AS DatabaseName, 
            CAST(name AS varchar), CAST(Value AS varchar) 
        FROM [?].sys.extended_properties WHERE class=0'
```

And if you want all the databases and just properties where they exist.

```
SELECT db.Name, #EP.PropertyName, #EP.PropertyValue
FROM sys.databases db
LEFT OUTER JOIN #EP
    ON db.name = #EP.DatabaseName
```

Comment: Let me try to follow your logic on the first bit, as I have not used SQL Server in a while. First you're creating a temporary table? Then populating it with all extended_properties from every database? (I am getting an error here btw saying "Incorrect syntax near sp_msforeachdb")  @Kenneth Fisher

Comment: @Hank, Sorry about the incorrect syntax.  I didn't put EXEC in front of sp_msforeachdb.  I even blogged about it recently and still forgot.  Oh well.  To the other part, yes, I am creating a temp table then sp_msforeachdb cycles through each database and I'm populating the temp table that way.  sp_msforeachdb replaces the ? with the database name.  Then once I have the temp table populated it's easy to query against sys.databases.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option, does not use temporary table but returns multiple results...

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb N'SELECT name, value 
FROM [?].sys.fn_listextendedproperty(default, default, default, default, default, default, default)'
```