# How to query a view's column's extended properties from the underlying source table?

Tags: sql-server, information-schema, extended-properties

I am looking for a way to query the 'MS_Description' extended property values of table columns that are returned in a view, not the extended property values on the view's columns itself.

I can get the view schema ([How to list the source table name of columns in a VIEW (SQL Server 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000999/how-to-list-the-source-table-name-of-columns-in-a-view-sql-server-2005)) which returns view columns used in a view (although I only want columns that are returned).

And I can get extended properties: [Select Extended Property from SQL Server tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714848/select-extended-property-from-sql-server-tables)

But I haven't worked out exactly how to marry the 2. But first, is there a built-in view or function that will automatically do this? I am using SQL 2014.

Or has anyone already written this query?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3abc/1

Comment: You can't directly. Those extended properties belong to the base table. If you look at sys.extended_properties you will see the major_id is the same as the object_id of your table. The columns in your view are not the same column as in your base table. You would have to leverage dynamic sql to even have a chance at this. But why do you need to get the extended properties of a column used in a view in the first place? The only thing I could think of is trying to leverage that data for a label caption on an input form that is bound to a view.

Comment: I'm using Enterprise Architect to generate a data dictionary, and I wanted to manually set the notes on the view w/ the table column description (software doesn't do it, so I'm trying to hack it).

Comment: It would be quite challenging to pull this off to say the least but a very interesting idea.